Chern classes over projective space
My goal is to calculate the first Chern class of line bundles over the projective space, i.e. $c_1(\mathcal{O}(n)), n\in \mathbb{Z}$
Wikipedia states that $c_1(\mathcal{O}(n))=n$.
I was really confused when I encounter the above statement. The reference I follow (Huybrechts's Complex Geometry, p.198) mentions that $c_k(E)\in H^{2k}(X,\mathbb{R})$. So I was considering $c_1(E)$ as a class of $2$-forms. In particular,  if we consider the hermitian structure $h=\frac{1}{1+\sum |z_i/z_0|^2}$ (the natural hermitian structure) it follows that $
F_{\nabla}=\frac{i}{2\pi}w_{FS}$, where $w_{FS}$ I denote the Fubini-Study metric. And thus $$ c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))=[\frac{i}{2\pi}w_{FS}]\in H^{2}(\mathbb{CP^n},\mathbb{R}).$$
Michael Albanese (great) answer provides an isomorphism $H^{2}(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$. So via this isomorphism I can understand $[w_{FS}]\leftrightarrow 1$.
$\bullet$ Why $c_1(E)\in H^{2}(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb{Z})$ and How
$H^{2}(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$?
If the isomorphism is given via $ H^{2}(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb{Z})\ni \omega\mapsto \int_{CP^1}\omega$,
then indeed $c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))=1$ since $\int_{CP^1}w_{FS}=1$.
But why in general $\int_{CP^1}\omega \in \mathbb{Z}$?. Is the case $n=1$ somehow special, or this treatment also works for $\mathbb{CP}^n$?
$\bullet$ Do we always have such isomorphisms ? i.e. $H^{2k}(X,\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}$?
Any comments, facts or insights that could help clarify these questions and help me understand better Chern classes would be greatly appreciated.

I just realized that I had forgotten a crucial fact about the Chern class. It's the same as the map $c_1: Pic(X)\to H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.  What a wonderful connection! So this answers why $c_1\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

The answer to your second question about isomorphisms in cohomology is "yes" by the universal coefficient theorem (and the vanishing of higher Ext when one of the inputs is a field).

@TabesBridges From my previous comment, don't we have that $c_1\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ for every complex manifold ? I am not familiar with the universal coefficient theorem. So the isomorphism $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$ is given by the integral evaluation I wrote ?

Sure, you can integrate forms (and hence cohomology classes) with coefficients living in whatever ring you desire. Based on the questions you're asking, I would suggest learning some more algebraic topology, as you seem to be somewhat unfamiliar with the role that coefficients play in (co)homology theory.
